# Will JavaScripts embedded in an HTML file loaded by WKWebView be accessible?

Tags: javascript, ios, swift

I have a basic `foo.html` in my iOS 10 application. The markup is straight forward:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title>Example</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Hello, World!</p>

        <div id="container"></div>
    </body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bar.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // Bar is defined in bar.js
        var bar = new Bar();
    </script>
</html>
```

I load it with the following:

```
let htmlFile = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "foo", ofType: "html")
let html = try? String(contentsOfFile: htmlFile!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
webView.loadHTMLString(html!, baseURL: nil)
```

In my iOS app, I'm trying to access the `bar` variable. After the DOM is loaded as confirmed by by WKNavigationDelegate's method: `func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!)`

I have code like this:

```
var htmlContent : String {
   var s = "console.log(bar)"

   return s
}

webView.evaluateJavaScript(htmlContent, completionHandler: { result, error in
  if let error = error {
    print("error: \(error)")
  }

  if let result = result {
    print("result: \(result)")
  }
})
```

I end up getting an error:

```
error: Error Domain=WKErrorDomain Code=4 "A JavaScript exception occurred" UserInfo={WKJavaScriptExceptionLineNumber=1, WKJavaScriptExceptionMessage=ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Bar, WKJavaScriptExceptionSourceURL=about:blank, NSLocalizedDescription=A JavaScript exception occurred, WKJavaScriptExceptionColumnNumber=47}
```

Is what I'm trying to do possible? Do I have to approach the problem a different way? Does `evaluateJavaScript` have access to the scope of my DOM after it's loaded because as of right now, it seems it does not.

Comment: Are you showing exactly the same code when you get that error? `WKJavaScriptExceptionColumnNumber=47` is suggesting that the JavaScript code passed to `webView.evaluateJavaScript` has at least 48 characters, but your `htmlContent` has only 16. Without showing the right info, no one can help you.

Comment: It's not the exact code, but the exact code wouldn't help with context by any means right now. It does exactly what this example is doing and that's trying to create an object that's namespace/code is available in `bar.js`, except it seems as if it cannot access the contents of `bar.js` and/or it is out of scope.

Comment: Exact code would help to eliminate the possibilities of many slight mistakes. Anyway, the bounty would help you. Good luck.

Comment: @randombits, can you please let me know how you designed your WKWebView? what are the properties you added to then WKWebView?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I figured it out - will put the answer here hoping it helps someone else:

The problem was here:

`webView.loadHTMLString(html!, baseURL: nil)`

I had to ensure `baseURL` is not nil, the following fixes it:

`webView.loadHTMLString(html!, baseURL: Bundle.main.bundleURL)`

Comment: Rest In Peace 500 rep :(

Comment: @FrankerZ and randombits, Is form loading properly?

Comment: Thank you, It helped me a lot. Thanks a ton @randombits.